# @font-face not being applied, not loading

Tags: font-face

For some reason my @font-face isn't working.

```
@font-face{
font-family: "Manteka";
src: url('../fonts/manteka.ttf');}
```

I'm trying to use it for my navigation links

```
#nav a {
font-family: "Manteka", Verdana, Tahoma;}
```

Quick folder layout

My CSS file is in a 'css' folder inside 'www'
index file is located in 'www'
font file is inside 'fonts' folder inside 'www'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloaded the files from another source and used this

```
@font-face { /* The manteka Font, use it by call font-family directly */
            font-family: 'manteka';
            src: url('../fonts/manteka.eot'); /* For IE */
            src: url('../fonts/manteka.ttf') format('truetype'), /* For Chrome and Safari */
                 url('../fonts/manteka.woff') format('woff'); /* For FireFox */}
```

Works fine now, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding format('truetype')

```
@font-face{
font-family: "Manteka";
src: url('../fonts/manteka.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, try dropping the quotes on the usage:

```
#nav a {
font-family: Manteka, Verdana, Tahoma;}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything :/

Comment: Is the font path and file accessible by your browser?  Did you run the debugger on your browser to see what resource files were accessed?

Comment: When I type in the font path it downloads it so yeah, how do I run the debugger?

Comment: The debugger is browser dependent.  On Chrome it would be shift-ctrl-i for example.  Also try referencing the font-family without the quotes.

Comment: Sources doesn't list the font, tried without quotes

Comment: Don't you use another css file that may overwrite `#nav a` rules of your own? try to add `!important` at the end of `font-family:...` line

Comment: my chrome's sources also don't show fonts files, but it works.